# Enum wrapped in a struct

Tags: c#, enum, wrapper

I was thinking about how I was going to use some enums I made, how I was going to make sure they had valid values and how to call the class which would contain the necessary extensions methods. And then I thought: why not wrap the enum in a struct. I wrote up a little example code and it looks like this (ignore the fact that it's a very common day enum, I needed something as an example):

```
public struct Day
{
    private enum DayE
    {
        Monday = 1,
        Tuesday,
        Wednesday,
        Thursday,
        Friday
    }

    private readonly DayE value;

    public static Day Monday { get { return new Day( DayE.Monday ); } }
    public static Day Tuesday { get { return new Day( DayE.Tuesday ); } }
    public static Day Wednesday { get { return new Day( DayE.Wednesday ); } }
    public static Day Thursday { get { return new Day( DayE.Thursday ); } }
    public static Day Friday { get { return new Day( DayE.Friday ); } }

    private Day( DayE value )
    {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        switch( value )
        {
            case DayE.Monday:
                return "mo";
            case DayE.Tuesday:
                return "tu";
            case DayE.Wednesday:
                return "we";
            case DayE.Thursday:
                return "th";
            case DayE.Friday:
                return "fr";
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException( "Can't convert 0 value" );
        }
    }
}
```

Some advantages of this approach I could think of:

- Allows you to limit the possible values, only the ones you construct using the private constructor can be made. (Of course, the 0 value can always be constructed using `default(Day)` or `new Day()`.) This means you only have to test if the value is not 0 to make sure it's valid. If 0 is a valid value, you don't have to test for validity.
- No need for an helper class for the extension methods, you can just put them in the struct. Also, you can override the `ToString` method, as can be seen in the example.
- In a similar fashion, `static` methods are now possible.
- I think it should be equally fast to just using the enum, since the compiler will probably take away most of the wrapper. Unless, of course, you add functionality, like validity checks, to methods.

Disadvantages:

- Need to create public static properties for all enum values. Although this does allow you to create extra values from combinations of other values, that you don't want to put in the enum itself (useful for tweaking the `ToString` behavior of a enum with Flags attribute).
- Need to define methods for all common enum functionality (for each wrapper you make), like `HasFlag` and `==`, `!=`, `&` and `|` operators. However, this gives you control over which of these methods/operators are available and it allows for validity checks inside them. It's possible to create one or more VS code snippets for this.
- Visual Studio's auto complete will be a little less happy with this. With enums it usually immediately auto selects the enum type name when you type e.g. `Day x =`. With this you'll first have to (partially) type that.
- To use this in a switch statement, you need to make the internal value and enum public, because structs don't work in a switch.

What do you think of this construction? Can you name any more disadvantages? Would you recommend me not to use this?

Edit: found a new disadvantage, see last point above.

Comment: If you want to prevent use of the type via `default(Day)` and force consumers to acquire instances through the predefined properties, you could make `value` nullable. This may or may not be desirable.

Comment: Can you give some examples of extension methods which you are going to put in this struct?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Then you have the same problem, only with null values. Also, this will take away all the compiler optimizations which makes it close to using an enum performance-wise.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy That really depends on what you're gonna use it for, obviously. Could be things like validation, or special ways of printing the value for whatever reason. In this example you could make `PrevDay()` and `NextDay()` methods which take into account that the Monday comes after the Friday (and vice versa). These methods could actually be properties instead, which is impossible for enums. For validation, you could have different methods, e.g. if you have a Flags enum, one that validates if it's exactly one valid flag, and one that validates if it's a valid combination of flags.

Comment: I would look hard at making enums work before I did this.

Answer (score 4):

To use `static` instances of value types instead of plain `enum` isn't a *strange* thing. I can't discuss its merits because each case is different (for sure it's slightly slower but you will hardly notice that) but you can see it often (also in .NET Framework code.) Use it cum grano salis because IMO there aren't many use cases unless you want to *emulate* more *powerful* Java's `enum`.

What's wrong, in my opinion, is that you're mixing too many responsibilities inside the same class. Note that you also have code for representation (abbreviated *enum* value) which usually doesn't belong to domain.

Second point is to wrap the enum. If you use this *pattern* then you don't need an enum any more, just drop it and integer value (day of week) will have its own clear name.

Third point is initialization, you don't need a property, because `Day` is an immutable value type your code may be simplified to a `static readonly` field.

Let's imagine to declare your `struct` like this:

```
public struct Day
{
    public static readonly Day Monday = new Day(1);
    public static readonly Day Tuesday = new Day(2);

    private Day(int dayOfWeek)
    {
        _dayOfWeek = dayOfWeek;
    }

    private readonly int _dayOfWeek;
}
```

Now we have to make it easy to use during our debugging sessions (and integer value isn't so friendly). We have two options here, adding another field with long name (which eventually might hold also the short one) like this:

```
public static readonly Day Monday = new Day(nameof(Monday), 1);
```

Note that the main point is to keep everything in **one single point**. To add another day (!), for example Sunday, you need to change only one point in your code.

If you need it only for debugging then I'd avoid to override `ToString()` and I'd go with `DebuggerDisplayAttribute` but it's a matter of preference. `ToString()` is sometimes the mandatory choice for type conversion in many poor-designed libraries and I'd avoid to use it as debugging aid when I have better options.

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{_name}")]
public struct Day { /* */ }
```

Second option is to write a type ad-hoc for debugging purposes without polluting your value type with unused and *heavy* strings. Let's introduce `DebuggerTypeProxyAttribute`:

```
[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(DayDebugView))]
public struct Day { /* */ }
```

In `DayDebugView` you can put everything you need for debugging:

```
internal sealed class DayDebugView
{
    public DayDebugView(Day day)
    {
        _day;
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            // Pseudo-code with some Reflection Magic
            // To get the static field name...
            return FindStaticFieldByValue(typeof(Day), _day)?.Name;
        }
    }

    private readonly Day _day;
}
```

---

Now you're done (in one way or another) with your debugging aid. If you need a presentation value then get rid of those hard-coded strings (because they're not localization friendly). Note that you might want, it depends on your usage pattern, use/implement `IFormatProvider` (in a separate class), implement `IFormattable`, implement a `TypeConverter` (in a separate class), implement `IConvertible` or use `ValueConverterAttribute` and implement `IValueConverter`. Which one is better/required depends on your UI requirements. For UI `ToString()` is just an abused handy method...

---

Add to all the above also code for comparison (at least overriding `Equals()` and implementing `IEquatable<T>` but probably also `==` and `!=`), eventually type conversions (to/from integers?), parsing to/from strings, serialization and...do you also need flags? Then few test to exercise you did everything correctly and you will ask yourself why you're not using a simple `enum` (with few lines of validation when it's an input.) Yes, **sometimes you will need this structure but less often than you might imagine**.

Comment: Thanks for your lengthy answer. I realize you don't want to go through this every time you create a struct, but you could create a partial struct and use that over and over (why can't I inherit struct code...).

The reason I used an enum instead of an integer for the internal value, is that it uses just one int of memory, while still allowing for usage of the enum's `ToString` and things like enumerating possible values.

Comment: A partial struct is just...copy & paste (or a code snippet which can be easily renamed.) Yes, you might do it but there should be a good reason to prefer this over an enum (which anyway you won't find yourself to use _too_ often.) If the only reason is _integrity_ (to avoid bugs like `Day day = (Day)43738`) then input validation is more than enough.

Comment: To be sealed let the compiler (and especially JIT compiler) be able to perform a more aggressive optimization and to keep them lightweight. Moreover there are other bigger differences: less overhead, ignoring boxing there isn't memory wasted for references, faster and _cheaper_ allocation...

Comment: Why would an enum be better for memory than a struct with just an enum inside? It's exactly the same in memory.

Also, I realize it's more work to write the struct itself, but using it will be easier, because you don't have to take care of validation anymore and can use `ToString` if necessary.

Comment: Performance: if you don't do anything with that enum then yes...check compiler generated code and you will see that, for example, even a simple comparison has very different IL code. Clarity: using an enum it's clear (for you and future readers of your code) that it is a fixed set of values. With a struct it's not. Easy of use: you can convert back and forward from enum/string/integer but with structs you might need Reflection for that. ToString() isn't something you should see often in your _domain model_. It's either for debugging or for presentation (and they shouldn't belong to your model)

Comment: Note that I am not saying "do not ever do it!". What I am saying is that it's not a 1:1 replacement for `enum` and you should carefully consider when to use it (if you feel you need a `struct` then it might also be that `enum` wasn't the right choice...)

Comment: I agree that you should only use something like this if you're gonna be using the struct a lot and it will spare you a lot of programming time. However, the point that the IL code is very different is not very relevant imo. I looked at the disassembly (of a release build) of a simple use case and it was basically the same. I know it's hard to really compare assembly code, especially with a small example, but it gives a better clue on performance than the IL code, because the JIT compiler takes away a lot of abstraction layers.

Comment: We probably won't ever care about a so small optimization (unless we're working with true performance critical code) but generated code is far to be similar. If you're overloading `==` operator, code is small enough and JIT decides to inline all the calls then you end more or less with same code (just a `cmp` instead of `sete` in my case.) If code you try is too trivial then everything is just optimized away by the JIT compiler. If you're instead (also indirectly) using `Object.Equals()` then assembly code is very different (function calls and so on instead of two `mov` and a simple `sete`. )

Comment: But the point I was pushing isn't performance but clarity. If somewhere I see you're assigning an `enum` then I immediately understand it's bla bla bla. If I see a `struct` then I have to go to its definition and _study_ its code. That said I sometimes use `struct` instead of `enum` when I need something _smarter_ (same as Java's enum, for example)

Comment: I agree that using an `enum` will be instantly clear to anyone.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that since `value` is populated from the constructor, which can only be called with values that you control, checking for invalid values is kind of superfluous.  Thus your `ToString` could look something like this:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return value.ToString().Substring(0, 2).ToLower();
}
```

Comment: You're right, though you still need to check for 0. It was just an example, but there's all kinds of things you can do in `ToString`. Especially when using flags, you can do some special thing to combine names.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to keep an `enum` while having some extra features, at some marginal cost you could consider decorating it with custom attributes, to mimic your requirements of your `ToString()`

```
public enum Day
{
    [ShortString("mo")]
    Monday = 1,
    [ShortString("tu")]
    Tuesday,
    [ShortString("we")]
    Wednesday,
    [ShortString("th")]
    Thursday,
    [ShortString("fr")]
    Friday
}

public class ShortStringAttribute : Attribute
{
    public ShortStringAttribute(string value)
    {
        // Do stuff with it.   
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an option, if that's the only thing you want. However, this takes away all the other advantages and does not work with methods like `string.Format`.

Comment: Well, you could create an Attribute to handle other scenarios as well. There really isn't much limitations on how far you can go with attributes. :)